# Hibernate with MS SQL

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm trying to integrate hibernate with MS SQL, below is the sql query I get from hibernate

```
12:27:44,172 DEBUG [AbstractSaveEventListener] Executing identity-insert immediately
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        aide.dbo.rule
        (appId, ruleName) 
    values
        (?, ?)
```

causes error

```
12:27:44,229 DEBUG [SqlExceptionHelper] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'rule'. [n/a]
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'rule'.
```

same error is thrown in MS SQL management studio too

### while this command runs fine

> ```
>  insert 
>     into
>         [aide].[dbo].[rule]
>         (appId, ruleName) 
>     values
>         ('rf', 'wfw')
> ```

### below is my hibernate cfg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property> -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_catalog">aide</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">dbo</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">aide</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">aide</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property><!-- JDBC connection pool (use the 
            built-in) -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="com.****.Rule" />

        <!-- <mapping resource="com/****/Rules.hbm.xml"></mapping> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

(sqljdbc4.jar downloaded from microsoft website)
seems hibernate is generating a query not understandable by MS SQL

Comment: No, -you- are. By using the keyword 'rule' as a name. The error is already telling you that: "Incorrect syntax near the KEYWORD 'rule'". But you're not listening.

Comment: OP's phrasing is legitimate. There are situations where there is very good reason for using a reserved keyword as a table name, and pretty much every DBMS allows it with some form of escaping. The problem that led me, and probably OP, here was _how to best do it in the context of hibernate_. I have a hard requirement of supporting multiple DBMS's, must add SQL Server support to an existing entity structure, and need a form of escaping that is understood by all of the ones I must support.

The table name is not a reserved keyword in any of the other DBMSs I must support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RULE` is a SQL Server reserved [keyword](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

If you need to stick to that name you need to escape it with:

```
@Table(name="`rule`")
```