# Hibernate mssql dialect [SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.]

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have following code:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.party.id = :id")
List<User> findUsersByPartyId(@Param("id") Long id);
```

In logs I see:

```
org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
```

and then error:

```
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.
```

I tried to wrap it with [](`SELECT u FROM [User]...`) but at this case I see error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: [ near line 1, column 15 [SELECT u FROM [User] u WHERE u.party.id = :id]
```

How to fix it if I cannot rename tables?

Comment: `u` is an alias of `User`. What columns are you selecting?

Comment: I want obtain all columns

Comment: Then use `u.*`.

Comment: Are you joking?

Comment: *QuerySyntaxException: expecting IDENT, found '*' near line 1, column 10 [SELECT u.* FROM com.finvale.entities.User*

Comment: Must be a long day... I'm totally missing something here... Sorry.

Comment: See accepted answer and see if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053894/hibernate-with-ms-sql

Comment: With the code being `@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.party.id = :id")`, this should change to `@Query("SELECT u.* FROM User u WHERE u.party.id = :id")`

Comment: Try log the native sql that hibernate is using to query, it will probably help you find the cause of the problem.

Comment: Sadly your JPA provider doesn't auto-quote SQL keywords, so USER is a problem for it. Some JPA providers do auto-quote such things